# Multiline TextField with axis doesn't wrap over several lines with SwiftUI for watchOS

Tags: swiftui, watchos

This is my View:

```
@State private var descriptionService: String = "Hello Tim it doesnt work at all"
TextField("description".localized, text: $descriptionService, axis: .vertical)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .padding()
    .lineLimit(3...7)
```

And this is the result:

[image]

According to the `axis` parameter the text field should be multilined, but it is not. Why is this?

Comment: Would you expand what "doesn't work" means in the context of this problem? Please add the information into the question itself, by way of an edit.

Comment: @halfer have you read the question carefully? If yes, then you could see that it doesnt work because question says about multiline text field. But there is only one line. Should be more, but it is one. Why?

Comment: The amendment to the question is an improvement. Perhaps the subtext was not clear - avoid the phrase "doesn't work" at all costs in your questions. It is often said on Stack Overflow that it is the least helpful fault report possible.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Doesn't work - do not use it.